# Removing forks in a shell script so that it runs well in Cygwin

Tags: linux, windows, shell, cygwin, fork

I'm trying to run a shell script on windows in Cygwin. The problem I'm having is that it runs extremely slowly in the following section of code. From a bit of googling, I believe its due to there being a large amount of fork() calls within the script and as windows has to use Cygwins emulation of this, it just slows to a crawl.

A typical scenario would be in Linux, the script would complete in < 10 seconds (depending on file size) but in Windows on Cygin for the same file it would take nearly 10 minutes.....

So the question is, how can i remove some of these forks and still have the script return the same output. I'm not expecting miracles but I'd like to cut that 10 minute wait time down a fair bit.

Thanks.

```
check_for_customization(){
  filename="$1"    
  extended_class_file="$2"
  grep "extends" "$filename" | grep "class" | grep -v -e '^\s*<!--' | while read line; do 
    classname="$(echo $line | perl -pe 's{^.*class\s*([^\s]+).*}{$1}')"
    extended_classname="$(echo $line | perl -pe 's{^.*extends\s*([^\s]+).*}{$1}')"

    case "$classname" in
    *"$extended_classname"*) echo "$filename"; echo "$extended_classname |$classname | $filename" >> "$extended_class_file";;
    esac
  done
}
```

**Update**: Changed the regex a bit and used a bit more perl:

```
check_for_customization(){
  filename="$1"    
  extended_class_file="$2"
  grep "^\(class\|\(.*\s\)*class\)\s.*\sextends\s\S*\(.*$\)" "$filename" | grep -v -e '^\s*<!--' | perl -pe 's{^.*class\s*([^\s]+).*extends\s*([^\s]+).*}{$1 $2}' | while read classname extended_classname; do
    case "$classname" in
    *"$extended_classname"*) echo  "$filename"; echo "$extended_classname | $classname | $filename" >> "$extended_class_file";;
    esac
  done
}
```

So, using the above code, the run time was reduced from about 8 minutes to 2.5 minutes. Quite an improvement.

If anybody can suggest any other changes I would appreciate it.

Comment: Does `bash -x` support your theory?

Comment: its hard to tell for sure, but that call is executed in a loop and is the final part of the overall script. It seems that the loop calling this function takes seconds on Linux (Ubuntu 13.04) and minutes on Windows 7 with similar hardware.

Answer (score 3):

Put more commands into one perl script, e. g.

```
check_for_customization(){
  filename="$1" extended_class_file="$2" perl -n - "$1" <<\EOF
next if /^\s*<!--/;
next unless /^.*class\s*([^\s]+).*/; $classname = $1;
next unless /^.*extends\s*([^\s]+).*/; $extended_classname = $1;
if (index($extended_classname, $classname) != -1)
{
    print "$ENV{filename}\n";
    open FILEOUT, ">>$ENV{extended_class_file}";
    print FILEOUT "$extended_classname |$classname | $ENV{filename}\n"
}
EOF
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I run this, it spits out the error message Unmatched ) in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/Type) <-- HERE / at - line 4, <> line 160. 

It runs for a few seconds first then crashes

Comment: I see... I changed the code so that it doesn't treat $classname as a regular expression.

Comment: Changed the code to what you have now but it simply prints out a single line of text when the script finishes. The version I use above will print every class that is extended and the number of times it was extended in console and to a file. Thanks for your help though. If you can suggest any changes to the code I posted above I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Somehow, a change I had made to my example seemed to be missing... I recreated it above, but can't test any more this week.